# Red eye removal android

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to implement red eye removal application on android. Is there any api or built in android method to do this? If no then please tell me how can we detect eyes from image? I know how to remove red color but Im having difficulty in detecting eyes from image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the [FaceDetector.findFaces()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) which works for Bitmaps. However, it will just give you a Rectangle of the Face. But it should be easier to search in that rectangle for red-saturated pixels and desaturate the color as Alexander suggested. But this way you don't necessarly need another library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) to detect the eyes and then in the circular region where you expect the pupils to be, take the pixel value and set the Red value to, say, 20% of its original value while leaving the Green and Blue channels untouched.

Comment: Integrating open cv and using it to detect eyes is itself a difficult task for me. Is there any simple way to remove red eye???

Comment: Image processing is not an easy thing to do. You'll need to use a library to do it, otherwise you'll have to write the algorithm yourself. I'm sure there are many resources to be found on Google about image processing and red eye removal.

Comment: @UmairZahid If it is too difficult, maybe it doesn't belong in your app.